# linux: one apache two php versions. possible?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php

it seems that some of my php applications require php 5.2 and some require php 5.3.
is there a way to configure apache (v2.2.14) that one virtualhost will work with one php library and a different virtualhost will require a different one?

currently the only solution that i found is to install two apaches and two phps and each of the apache will reside in a different port.

thanks

Comment: Poor application design if people are coding for a point release rather than a major release. Generally, point releases shouldn't have breaking changes in them.

Comment: Have you tried running the PHP 5.2 app on PHP 5.3?

Comment: While point release SHOULDN'T have breaking changes the reality is that PHP 5.3 does indeed break code that runs perfectly on 5.2.

Comment: Some versions of Drupal 5.x won't run properly on PHP 5.3... Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use PHP 4 and 5 it would be easy to manipulate what module you want to use with:

```
<IfModule mod_php5.c> 
<IfModule mod_php4.c>
```

So there 3 ways to deal with this problem:

1. Correct the problems in the PHP scripts (imho the best way)
2. Modify the PHP source code so it reports itself as "mod_php52.c","mod_php53.c"
3. Run it as CGI where needed Check it out [here](http://hurring.com/scott/howto/php4_and_php5/)

You can also run 2 servers on different ports and use a proxy

Comment: You link is 404

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. You should use fastcgi mode by "FcgidWrapper" directive in apache configuration. This way you can define different fastcgi handler daemons for different url extension, path, or even virtual hosts. In the background, each fastcgi daemon then can easily executes different php versions.

Answer (score 0):

I use [PHPfarm](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/Introducing%20phpfarm.htm) to [run many PHP versions](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/Running%20Apache%20with%20a%20dozen%20PHP%20versions.htm) on one apache instance. Works absolutely fine.

You basically install alternative PHP versions as CGI and use them to handle `.php` files in certain vhosts.